# Fullcalendar null end date when selecting events till midnight

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In weekAgenda view, I want to be able to create events that repeats on days of week(dow). However, adding dow option to events causes a end time to be null when it tries to render an event who's end time is midnight. The end time works fine when you resize a date.

What I've tried:

- removing dow attribute to events solve the bug, however, this does not meet my requirements.
- Forcing end time to be end of time. (No appropriate event to force end time. Adding it in eventRender causes events to disappear)

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aob9rouw/

```
allDay: false
_end: null
_id: "_fc72"
_recurring: true
_start: n
allDay: false
className: Array[0]
dow: Array[1]
end: null
start: n
__proto__: Object
```

(end time is set to null, when selecting a period which ends at midnight)

Edit:
Workaround check if event.end is 00:00, if so, set event end time to '24:00'